# 2 cookies 1 webpage, internet explorer 11 iframe vs full page cookie handling

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, cookies

Assume you first browse

***a.html*** : sends a cookie

then you go to

**b.html** and in an iframe it loads

***a.html*** : sends another cookie

In Internet Explorer 11, those two cookies are handled as **two different cookies**, whereas in Chrome and Firefox, they are **the same cookie**

How can I merge those two cookies for IE (make it act like Chrome or Firefox for this cookie)?

PS: there is P3P on a.html and b.html already, did not work

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, untrusted certificate on a.html